# Написання ініціалів: разом чи окремо?

Tags: пунктуація, типографіка, разом-дефіс-окремо

Чи можна писати ініціали (поруч із прізвищем) разом чи потрібно ставити пробіл між ім'ям та по батькові?

Наприклад,

> Л.П. Косач

чи

> Л. П. Косач

Чи є правило, яке це регулює?

---

Can I write initials (next to the name) together or need to put a space between the name and surname?

> Л.П. Косач

or

> Л. П. Косач

Is there are rule about this?

Comment: Наскільки я пам'ятаю - без прогаликів пишуться абревіатури, а ініціали - це не абревіатури. Так мені колись пояснювали.

Comment: Обговорення на уа-мова: http://ua-mova.livejournal.com/1223099.html, правила Вікіпедії: https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%96%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%96%D1%8F:%D0%9E%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83

Comment: @Sasha  начебто, й загальновідомий факт, але я чомусь примудряюся натрапити на виняток ([наприклад](http://www.library.univ.kiev.ua/ukr/elcat/new/detail.php3?doc_id=1378111))

Comment: @NashBridges А чого дивуватися, якщо у книжці, де знайшли документальне підтвердження норми ("Довідник художнього і технічного редакторів" [пдф](http://www.marsel.ru/files/Gilenson.pdf)) на обкладинці її порушено? Переклад мій: "Скорочення повинні бути відокремлені від чисел чи слів, які їх стосуються, на напівкегельну. Так само повинні бути розділені між собою і від фамілії ініціали. У журнальних, газетних, інформаційних виданнях і виданнях оперативної поліграфії допустимі відбивки міжсловним пробілом".

Comment: @NashBridges, ну, вони там насправді і лапки «"» замість апострофа «’» ставлять. Тож це виглядає більш схоже на внутрішній стандарт оформлення електронних описів документів (у бібліотеці ім. М. Максимовича) (сформований так через якісь технічні причини — або через незнання кращих альтернатив тими, хто приймав це рішення) — ніж на оформлення «для людей». Ну, але я не кажу, що винятків не існує — їх дофіга.

Comment: @Artemix, я все ж заперечу, що цей PDF більше виглядає схожим на *оцифрування* довідника, ніж на *точний скан* (там, здається, немає графічного шару) чи на *першоджерело* (у 1972/1988 не було формату PDF). Тобто сам довідник, можливо, мав пристойне оформлення, а це вже похибки того, хто робив оцифрування (*третьої особи*). В тому ж правописі в ел. і пап. варіантах відрізняєтся постановка прогалків («гр.␣//␣Іваненко» vs «гр.//␣Іваненко») — не кажучи вже про лапки й інше.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

#### Окремо.

Аргументи:

1. В прикладах у правописі ([§ 42.1](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil1.htm#par42p1)) — окремо. Так, ці приклади ілюструють трішки інше, але прецедент є. Можна подивитися [друкований варіант правопису](http://litopys.org.ua/pdf/pravopys2015.pdf) (щоб переконатися, що це не дефекти оцифрування).
2. [Отут](http://ua-mova.livejournal.com/1223099.html?thread=16951995#t16951995) (дякую, Artemix'е, за [коментар](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/999#comment2532_999)) дуже слушний аргумент: немає правил, які би предписували відділяти скорочення слів (у більшості випадків, в т. ч. імена) інакше, ніж самі слова. Відповідно: «місто␣Київ» → «м.␣Київ» (прогалок залишається), «соціал-демократичний» → «с.-д.» (прогалки не з'являються), «Іван␣Петрович␣Лобода» → «І.␣П.␣Лобода» або «І.␣П.␣Л.» (прогалки лишаються), «Богдан-Ігор␣Антонич» → «Б.-І.␣Антонич» (все як було).
3. Прогалки у відповідній ситуації [ставляться](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/78-init) в російській типографіці (яка не зобов'язана збігатися з нашою, але на яку ми часто оглядаємось). Причому там [рекомендують](//ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BB#.D0.9F.D1.80.D0.BE.D0.B1.D0.B5.D0.BB_.D0.BF.D1.80.D0.B8_.D1.82.D0.B8.D0.BF.D0.BE.D0.B3.D1.80.D0.B0.D1.84.D1.81.D0.BA.D0.BE.D0.BC_.D0.BD.D0.B0.D0.B1.D0.BE.D1.80.D0.B5) ставити прогалок нормальної ширини, а не зменшеної (на відміну від, наприклад, «15 000», «5° C» і другого прогалку в «і т. п.»). В англійській мові — [по-різному](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/11332/139407), але частіше ставлять.

#### Але не можна розривати між рядками.

Саме про це був вищенаведений § 42.1:

> Не можна переносити прізвища, залишаючи в кінці попереднього рядка ініціали або інші умовні скорочення, що до них відносяться: *Т. Г. Шевченко* (а не *Т. Г. // Шевченко*), *гр. Іваненко* (а не *гр. // Іваненко*), *акад. (доц., проф.) Гончаренко* (а не *акад. (доц., проф.) // Гончаренко*), *тов. Гнатюк* (а не *тов. // Гнатюк*).

Саме тому дехто у випадках неможливості чи складності постановки [нерозривних прогалків](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%96%D0%BB) обирає не ставити прогалки взагалі — адже ширина (і, відповідно, наявність) прогалків — це питання значною мірою типографічне, а неможливість розриву зафіксована в правописі.

Comment: Для практичного вжитку, рекомендується у HTML-based редакторах вживати макрос `&nbsp;`, а у повнофункціональних текстових редакторах — `Shift+Space` або іншу комбінацію клавіш, яку варто запам'ятати.

Comment: @bytebuster, так, звісно. Але воно не всюди працює. Наприклад, тут у коментарях: не лише `&nbsp;` не спрацьовує — а й явним чином поставлені нерозривні пробіли замінюються на звичайні. Але в запитаннях/відповідях `&nbsp;` працює (візуалізується як нерозривний пробіл) — може, комусь це буде корисно.

Comment: @bytebuster, чесно — не вважаю. По-моєму, це окрема велика тема. (У ворді, наприклад, не Shift+Space, AFAIK; плюс воно не копіюється в буфер обміну з Firefox — відповідно, через copy/paste губиться; плюс ще 100500 нюансів.) Але можу прибрати свої коментарі, щоб Ваш єдиний перший було краще видно користувачам — раптом, комусь знадобиться.

Answer (score 10):

До відповіді Sasha хотів би додати що використання пробілів не регулюються правописом, тому що терміну "[пробіл](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%96%D0%BB)" (чи "прогалок") у правописі немає.

Використання пробілів (і взагалі їх існування) це особливості друкарсько-видавничого процесу і те, як вони використовуються описано у документах що стосуються створення друкованих текстів. А саме — це довідники для працівників видавництв і (можливо) посібники для користувачів друкарських машинок.

Ну і відповідно, відповіді по посиланнях, що навів Sasha апелюють до ГОСТів, довідників, спеціальної літератури, але не до правил, правописів і т.і.

Власне, поки люди не користувалися інтернетом для спілкування, особливості використання прогалків не були цікаві широкому загалу, тепер все це змінилося.

Щоб все-ж таки навести приклад стандарту оформлення ініціалів процитую книгу 1988 року видання "Довідник художнього і технічного редакторів" [пдф](http://www.marsel.ru/files/Gilenson.pdf) у власному перекладі з російської:

> Скорочення повинні бути відокремлені від чисел чи слів, які їх стосуються, на напівкегельну*. Так само повинні бути розділені між собою і від прізвища ініціали. У журнальних, газетних, інформаційних виданнях і виданнях оперативної поліграфії допустимі відбивки міжсловним прогалком.

* напівкегельна — це напівкегельна шпація (англійською en-space), тобто прогалок, ширина якого відповідає ширині літери n.

Для тих кому цікаво — великий список щодо [правил використання прогалків](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BB#.D0.9F.D1.80.D0.BE.D0.B1.D0.B5.D0.BB_.D0.BF.D1.80.D0.B8_.D1.82.D0.B8.D0.BF.D0.BE.D0.B3.D1.80.D0.B0.D1.84.D1.81.D0.BA.D0.BE.D0.BC_.D0.BD.D0.B0.D0.B1.D0.BE.D1.80.D0.B5) <sub>рос.</sub> у типографському наборі.

Comment: Ще додам, що [тут](http://ru-typography.livejournal.com/54480.html?thread=183504#t183504) (цитуючи «Справочник технолога-полиграфиста. Часть 1. Наборные процессы» М. В. Шульмейстера та Г. А. Таля — Москва, «Книга», 1981) пишуть, що оптимальною міжслівною шпацією для тексту вважається півкегельна. Тобто «напівкегельну шпацію» можна вважати «звичайним» за шириною прогалком.

Comment: Наскільки я зрозумів, звичайний прогалок трохи розтягується або звужується в залежності від кількості слів у рядку (щоб рядок займав ширину колонки), а відділяти ініціали треба "нерозтяжними" прогалками. Але то технічні деталі для спеціалістів.

Comment: Можливо, Ви праві, але: (1) при «рваному» правому краї (flush left), який зараз набуває популярності, це неактуально; (2) мені не віриться, що при звуженні звичайних відступів (менше за 0,5) відступи між ініціалами мають бути *ширшими* за звичайні, інтуїція підзказує, що вони мають бути *не ширшими* за інші, відповідно, те, що при «фіксованому» правому краї (justified) вони, на відміну від інших прогалків, мусять мати фіксовану ширину, викликає сумніви.

Comment: В будь-якому разі то вже для спеціалістів нюанси.

Answer (score 6):

До попередніх відповідей можу додати, що в другий половині 80-х на курсах діловодства та машинного друку вчили, якщо ініціали попереду прізвища, прогалок не ставити, якщо навпаки - треба, прогалок між ім'ям та по батькові в ініціалах не ставити, тобто:

```
Л.П.Косач
Косач Л.П.
```

Зараз написання розшифрування підпису регламентується [ДСТУ 4163-2003](http://zakon3.rada.gov.ua/rada/show/v0055609-03)

Скани з книги "Делопроизводство Фельзер А.Б., Миссерман М.А. 1987":

http://i.share.pho.to/197ba2e5_l.jpeg

http://i.share.pho.to/fa9cd42a_l.jpeg

http://i.share.pho.to/aaa1256d_o.jpeg

http://i.share.pho.to/add65e6e_o.jpeg

Колеги з порталу DILOMOVA дають [зразок оформлення тексту документу](http://dilomova.org.ua/?p=65).

Тож бачимо, в тексті є зразки як з прогалками між ініціалів, так без них, можливо просто так набрано в типографії, тому що там свої правила набору. Оскільки друкарська машинка не має опції "нерозривного прогалку", тож, жеби візуально текст сприймався без зайвих прогалків, їх не ставили.